# How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?

Tags: sql-server, metadata

I am looking for T-SQL code to list all tables in all databases in SQL Server (at least in SS2005 and SS2008; would be nice to also apply to SS2000). The catch, however, is that I would like a ***single result set***. This precludes the otherwise excellent answer from [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/26/sql-server-list-all-the-tables-for-all-databases-using-system-tables/):

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS db, * from [?].sys.tables'
```

The above stored proc generates one result set ***per database***, which is fine if you are in an IDE like SSMS that can display multiple result sets. However, I want a single result set because I want a query that is essentially a "find" tool: if I add a clause like `WHERE tablename like '%accounts'` then it would tell me where to find my BillAccounts, ClientAccounts, and VendorAccounts tables regardless of which database they reside in.

---

### 2010.05.20 Update, about 20 minutes later...

So far, Remus' answer looks most interesting. Rather than post this as an answer and award it to myself, I am posting a version of it here that I have modified to include the DB name and a sample filter clause. It is looking like Remus will get the credit for the answer, though, at this point!

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'select b.name as "DB", a.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI as "Table", object_id, schema_id, cast(1 as int) as database_id  from master.sys.tables a join sys.databases b on database_id=1 where a.name like ''account%''';

select @sql = @sql + N' union all select b.name as "DB", a.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, object_id, schema_id, ' + cast(database_id as nvarchar(10)) + N' from ' + quotename(name) + N'.sys.tables a join sys.databases b on database_id=' + cast(database_id as nvarchar(10)) + 'where a.name like ''account%'''
from sys.databases where database_id > 1 

and state = 0
and user_access = 0;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

### 2010.05.24 Update -- New Front runner!

The feedback and answers have been great. Continued collaborative participation has led to a **new frontrunner**: KM's answer from May 21!

Here are the issues I uncovered with Remus' solution:

**Major issue:** Users have different permissions which leads the query to succeed based on the data (i.e. the filtering value). Run on my production database with ***no*** filtering (i.e. omitting the `WHERE` clause) I received this error on several DBs that I do not have permission to access:

> The server principal "msorens" is not able to access the database
> "ETLprocDB" under the current security context.

The query ***will*** succeed with some filtering clauses--those that do not touch the DBs outside my access level.

**Minor issue:** Not easily degradable to SQL Server 2000 support (yes, there are still some of us out there using it...) because it builds a single string while accumulating entries for each database. With my system, I surpassed the 8000-character mark at around 40 databases.

**Minor issue:** Duplicate code--the loop setup essentially duplicates the loop body. I understand the rationale but it is just a pet peeve of mine...

KM's answer is not afflicted by these issues. The stored proc `sp_msforeachdb` takes into account the user's permissions so it avoids permission problems. I have not yet tried the code with SS2000 but KM indicates the adjustments that should do it.

I am posting next my modifications to KM's answer based on my personal preferences. Specifically:

- I have removed the server name as it does not really add anything in the result set.
- I have split the name components into their own fields in the result set (db name, schema name, and table name).
- I have introduced separate filters for each of the three fields.
- I have added sorting by the three fields (which can be modified to your preferences).

Here is my modification to KM's code (with a sample filter applied just to the table name):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables table (DbName sysname,SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname)
DECLARE
     @SearchDb nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchSchema nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchTable nvarchar(200)
    ,@SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SearchDb='%'
SET @SearchSchema='%'
SET @SearchTable='%Account%'
SET @SQL='select ''?'' as DbName, s.name as SchemaName, t.name as TableName from [?].sys.tables t inner join [?].sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id WHERE ''?'' LIKE '''+@SearchDb+''' AND s.name LIKE '''+@SearchSchema+''' AND t.name LIKE '''+@SearchTable+''''

INSERT INTO @AllTables (DbName, SchemaName, TableName)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY DbName, SchemaName, TableName
```

Comment: +1 for resourcefulness, in hopes it will encourage others to perform due diligence.

Comment: check out my answer, it has a very simple, yet flexible way to search on any portion of the server+database+schema+table names

Comment: KM: Thanks for posting; I have updated my question to explain why I now prefer your solution.

Comment: `[?].sys.tables t inner join sys.schemas` will return only tables from schema dbo, you should `[?].sys.tables t inner join [?].sys.schemas` so you run the tables against the schemas from the same database.

Comment: I've updated the final answer to use [?].sys.schemas. I almost missed that myself. I don't normally update other people's answers but that seems like a super obvious oversight and I don't want others to use it without realizing they are only getting partial results (b/c in my case there are lots of duplicate IDs between databases so it actually did return a lot of tables from each db).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

for a simple way to get all tables on the server, try this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables table (CompleteTableName nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO @AllTables (CompleteTableName)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'select @@SERVERNAME+''.''+''?''+''.''+s.name+''.''+t.name from [?].sys.tables t inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id'
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY 1
```

it will return a single column that contains the server+database+schema+table name:
sample output:

```
CompleteTableName
--------------------------------------------
YourServer.YourDatabase1.YourSchema1.YourTable1
YourServer.YourDatabase1.YourSchema1.YourTable2
YourServer.YourDatabase1.YourSchema2.YourTable1
YourServer.YourDatabase1.YourSchema2.YourTable2
YourServer.YourDatabase2.YourSchema1.YourTable1
```

if you are not on SQL Server 2005 or up, replace the `DECLARE @AllTables table` with `CREATE TABLE #AllTables` and then every `@AllTables` with `#AllTables` and it will work.

**EDIT**
here is a version that will allow a search parameter to be used on any part or parts of the server+database+schema+table names:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables table (CompleteTableName nvarchar(4000))
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(4000)
       ,@SQL   nvarchar(4000)
SET @Search=null --all rows
SET @SQL='select @@SERVERNAME+''.''+''?''+''.''+s.name+''.''+t.name from [?].sys.tables t inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id WHERE @@SERVERNAME+''.''+''?''+''.''+s.name+''.''+t.name LIKE ''%'+ISNULL(@SEARCH,'')+'%'''

INSERT INTO @AllTables (CompleteTableName)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY 1
```

set @Search to NULL for all tables, set it to things like 'dbo.users' or 'users' or '.master.dbo' or even include wildcards like '.master.%.u', etc.

Comment: I got around to trying this on SQL Server 2000 and found that it does *not* work with the simple change you indicated--sys.tables and sys.schemas are not available until SS2005.

Comment: replace this one line: `SET @SQL='select @@SERVERNAME+''.''+''?''+''.''+s.name+''.''+t.name from [?]..sysobjects t inner join sysusers s on t.uid=s.uid WHERE @@SERVERNAME+''.''+''?''+''.''+s.name+''.''+t.name LIKE ''%'+ISNULL(@SEARCH,'')+'%'''`

Comment: Your inner join to sys.schemas is bad, missing databasename.

Comment: I believe that when setting the @SQL variable, `sys.schemas` should be replaced with `[?].sys.schemas`

Answer (score 17):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'select cast(''master'' as sysname) as db_name, name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, object_id, schema_id, cast(1 as int) as database_id  from master.sys.tables ';

select @sql = @sql + N' union all select ' + quotename(name,'''')+ ', name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, object_id, schema_id, ' + cast(database_id as nvarchar(10)) + N' from ' + quotename(name) + N'.sys.tables'
from sys.databases where database_id > 1
and state = 0
and user_access = 0;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: +1 very clever! Any way of adding the database name to the selected list of attributes, too?

Comment: Cool, but OP also wants to add a where clause, so you might have to factor that into the Dynamic SQL

Comment: I have modified this code to include the DB name (as suggested by marc_s) and the filter (as suggested by RobS) but since comments are limited, see the update in my question at the top of the page. (I chose to do that rather than add a separate answer since I am leaning towards giving Remus the credit at this point...)

Comment: I modified to project dbname too. One needs to be careful that the first db name in the union list determines the length of the result column, and if is too short it may truncate the subsequent dbname. I choose a cast to sysname (the type of sys.databases.name), and used the quotename function to properly add single quotes around the name coming from sys.databases. Didn't add where clause, since the OP knows how to do it :)

Comment: Good catch about the length... One more question: why do you explicitly specify the collation on the name?

Comment: Because on my server I have databases with different collations, and if you omit the collation you get conflicts on the union: `Cannot resolve collation conflict for column ... in SELECT statement.`

Answer (score 12):

I needed something that I could use to search all my servers using CMS and search by server, DB, schema or table. This is what I found (originally posted by Michael Sorens here: [How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do%20-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set) ).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables TABLE
        (
         ServerName NVARCHAR(200)
        ,DBName NVARCHAR(200)
        ,SchemaName NVARCHAR(200)
        ,TableName NVARCHAR(200)
        )
DECLARE @SearchSvr NVARCHAR(200)
       ,@SearchDB NVARCHAR(200)
       ,@SearchS NVARCHAR(200)
       ,@SearchTbl NVARCHAR(200)
       ,@SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SearchSvr = NULL  --Search for Servers, NULL for all Servers
SET @SearchDB = NULL  --Search for DB, NULL for all Databases
SET @SearchS = NULL  --Search for Schemas, NULL for all Schemas
SET @SearchTbl = NULL  --Search for Tables, NULL for all Tables

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME
        ,''?''
        ,s.name
        ,t.name
         FROM [?].sys.tables t 
         JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id 
         WHERE @@SERVERNAME LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchSvr, '') + '%''
         AND ''?'' LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchDB, '') + '%''
         AND s.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchS, '') + '%''
         AND t.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchTbl, '') + '%''
      -- AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''SSISDB'')
           '
-- Remove the '--' from the last statement in the WHERE clause to exclude system tables

INSERT  INTO @AllTables
        (
         ServerName
        ,DBName
        ,SchemaName
        ,TableName
        )
        EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT  *
FROM    @AllTables
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: I think you should use [?].sys.schemas instead of sys.schemas in the JOIN

Answer (score 4):

I quite like using INFORMATION_SCHEMA for this as I get the DB name for free.  That and - realising from @KM post that multiple results sets insert nicely - I came up with:

```
select top 0 * 
    into #temp
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

insert into #temp
    exec sp_msforeachdb 'select * from [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the common approach is to `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` for each database using `sp_MSforeachdb`

I created a snippet in VS Code that I think it might be helpful.

### Query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alltables', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #alltables;
SELECT * INTO #alltables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
TRUNCATE TABLE #alltables;
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];INSERT INTO #alltables SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
SELECT * FROM #alltables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%<TABLE_NAME_TO_SEARCH>%';
GO
```

### Snippet

```
{
    "List all tables": {
        "prefix": "sqlListTable",
        "body": [
            "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alltables', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #alltables;",
            "SELECT * INTO #alltables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;",
            "TRUNCATE TABLE #alltables;",
            "EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];INSERT INTO #alltables SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';",
            "SELECT * FROM #alltables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%$0%';",
            "GO"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I posted an answer a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675935/most-efficient-way-to-query-multiple-identical-tables-in-separate-databases) that you could use here. The outline is:

- Create a temp table
- Call sp_msForEachDb
- The query run against each DB stores the data in the temp table
- When done, query the temp table

Comment: It sounds like the asker would prefer a view-like interface, rather than a sproc, so that he can use SQL to filter the results. As far as I can tell, your suggestion makes this more difficult than it could be.

Comment: @WCWedin: Then use a normal table, rather than a temp table.  The only issue I see with this approach is that it can get out of sync if the data model is changing often (very bad anyways).

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Right, problems abound. This might turn out to be the best solution available, but it's hardly ideal. I'm not trying to be a critic, but ... well, I guess I am. I mean well, though.

Comment: My tactic would get the data, but it's not entirely clear what form the user needs to get the data in.  Note also that, in a stored procedure, you could embed code that checks SQL version number (@@Version), and based on that runs the necessary query--sys.tables, sysobjects, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old thread, but it was very helpful when I had to put together some system documentation for several different servers that were hosting different versions of Sql Server. I ended up creating 4 stored procedures which I am posting here for the benefit of the community. We use Dynamics NAV so the two stored procedures with NAV in the name split the Nav company out of the table name. Enjoy...

4 of 4 - ListServerDatabaseNavTables - for Dynamics NAV

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[ListServerDatabaseNavTables]
(
    @SearchDatabases varchar(max) = NULL,  
    @SearchSchema sysname = NULL,
    @SearchCompanies varchar(max) = NULL,
    @SearchTables varchar(max) = NULL,
    @ExcludeSystemDatabases bit = 1,
    @Sql varchar(max) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

/**************************************************************************************************************************************
* Lists all of the database tables for a given server.
*   Parameters
*       SearchDatabases - Comma delimited list of database names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                         Defaults to null  
*       SearchSchema - Schema name for which to search
*                      Defaults to null 
*       SearchCompanies - Comma delimited list of company names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                         Defaults to null  
*       SearchTables - Comma delimited list of table names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                      Defaults to null 
*       ExcludeSystemDatabases - 1 to exclude system databases, otherwise 0
*                          Defaults to 1
*       Sql - Output - the stored proc generated sql
*
*   Adapted from answer by KM answered May 21 '10 at 13:33
*   From: How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?
*   Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set
*
**************************************************************************************************************************************/

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @l_CompoundLikeStatement varchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @l_TableName sysname
    DECLARE @l_CompanyName sysname
    DECLARE @l_DatabaseName sysname

    DECLARE @l_Index int

    DECLARE @l_UseAndText bit = 0

    DECLARE @AllTables table (ServerName sysname, DbName sysname, SchemaName sysname, CompanyName sysname, TableName sysname, NavTableName sysname)

    SET @Sql = 
        'select @@ServerName as ''ServerName'', ''?'' as ''DbName'', s.name as ''SchemaName'', ' + char(13) +
        '       case when charindex(''$'', t.name) = 0 then '''' else left(t.name, charindex(''$'', t.name) - 1) end as ''CompanyName'', ' + char(13) +
        '       case when charindex(''$'', t.name) = 0 then t.name else substring(t.name, charindex(''$'', t.name) + 1, 1000) end as ''TableName'', ' + char(13) +
        '       t.name as ''NavTableName'' ' + char(13) +
        'from [?].sys.tables t inner join ' + char(13) + 
        '     sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id '

    -- Comma delimited list of database names for which to search
    IF @SearchDatabases IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + 'where (' + char(13)
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchDatabases)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchDatabases, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchDatabases = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchDatabases, @l_DatabaseName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' ''?'' like ''' + @l_DatabaseName + '%'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ')'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Search schema
    IF @SearchSchema IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            's.name LIKE ''' + @SearchSchema + ''' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS'
        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Comma delimited list of company names for which to search
    IF @SearchCompanies IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and (' ELSE 'where (' END + char(13) 
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchCompanies))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchCompanies)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_CompanyName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchCompanies))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_CompanyName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchCompanies, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchCompanies = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchCompanies, @l_CompanyName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' t.name like ''' + @l_CompanyName + '%'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ' )'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Comma delimited list of table names for which to search
    IF @SearchTables IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and (' ELSE 'where (' END + char(13) 
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchTables))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchTables)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_TableName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchTables))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_TableName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchTables, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchTables = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTables, @l_TableName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' t.name like ''$' + @l_TableName + ''' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ' )'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    IF @ExcludeSystemDatabases = 1 BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + case when @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            '''?'' not in (''master'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''model'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''msdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''tempdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)' 
    END

/*  PRINT @Sql  */

    INSERT INTO @AllTables 
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @Sql

    SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY DbName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, CompanyName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, TableName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
END
```

Answer (score 1):

[Link to a stored-procedure-less approach that Bart Gawrych posted on Dataedo site](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-all-tables-in-all-databases)

I was asking myself, 'Do we really have to use a stored procedure here?' and I found this helpful post. (The state=0 was added to fix issues with offline databases per feedback from users of the linked page.)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = 
    (select ' UNION ALL
        SELECT ' +  + quotename(name,'''') + ' as database_name,
               s.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
                    AS schema_name,
               t.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as table_name 
               FROM '+ quotename(name) + '.sys.tables t
               JOIN '+ quotename(name) + '.sys.schemas s
                    on s.schema_id = t.schema_id'
    from sys.databases 
    where state=0
    order by [name] for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)');

set @sql = stuff(@sql, 1, 12, '') + ' order by database_name, 
                                               schema_name,
                                               table_name';

execute (@sql);
```

Comment: Line 14 generates error `Incorrect syntax near 'for'.`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to loop through the list of databases and then list each table. You should be able to union them together.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run the sp_tables stored procedure. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260318(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: ... for every database. So at least `sp_msForEachDb 'USE [?] EXEC sp_tables'`, but that's still separate results.

Answer (score 0):

This is really handy, but I wanted a way to show all user objects, not just tables, so I adapted it to use sys.objects instead of sys.tables

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables table (DbName sysname,SchemaName sysname, ObjectType char(2), ObjectName sysname)
DECLARE
     @SearchDb nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchSchema nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchObject nvarchar(200)
    ,@SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SearchDb='%'
SET @SearchSchema='%'
SET @SearchObject='%Something%'
SET @SQL='select ''?'' as DbName, s.name as SchemaName, t.type as ObjectType, t.name as ObjectName 
from [?].sys.objects t inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id 
WHERE t.type in (''FN'',''IF'',''U'',''V'',''P'',''TF'') 
AND ''?'' LIKE '''+@SearchDb+''' 
AND s.name LIKE '''+@SearchSchema+''' 
AND t.name LIKE '''+@SearchObject+''''

INSERT INTO @AllTables (DbName, SchemaName, ObjectType, ObjectName)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY DbName, SchemaName, ObjectType, ObjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old thread, but it was very helpful when I had to put together some system documentation for several different servers that were hosting different versions of Sql Server. I ended up creating 4 stored procedures which I am posting here for the benefit of the community. We use Dynamics NAV so the two stored procedures with NAV in the name split the Nav company out of the table name. Enjoy...

1 of 4 - ListServerDatabases

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [pssi].[ListServerDatabases]    Script Date: 10/3/2017 8:56:45 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[ListServerDatabases]
(
    @SearchDatabases varchar(max) = NULL,  
    @ExcludeSystemDatabases bit = 1,
    @Sql varchar(max) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

/**************************************************************************************************************************************
* Lists all of the databases for a given server.
*   Parameters
*       SearchDatabases - Comma delimited list of database names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                         Defaults to null  
*       ExcludeSystemDatabases - 1 to exclude system databases, otherwise 0
*                                Defaults to 1
*       Sql - Output - the stored proc generated sql
*
*   Adapted from answer by 
*   From: How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?
*   Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set
*
**************************************************************************************************************************************/

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @l_CompoundLikeStatement varchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @l_DatabaseName sysname

    DECLARE @l_Index int

    DECLARE @lUseAndText bit = 0

    DECLARE @l_AllDatabases table (ServerName sysname, DbName sysname)

    SET @Sql = 
        'select @@ServerName as ''ServerName'', ''?'' as ''DbName'''

    IF @SearchDatabases IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + 'where (' + char(13)
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchDatabases)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchDatabases, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchDatabases = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchDatabases, @l_DatabaseName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' ''?'' like ''' + @l_DatabaseName + '%'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ' )'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @lUseAndText = 1
    END

    IF @ExcludeSystemDatabases = 1 BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + case when @lUseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            '''?'' not in (''master'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''model'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''msdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''tempdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)' 
    END

/*  PRINT @Sql  */

    INSERT INTO @l_AllDatabases 
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @Sql

    SELECT * FROM @l_AllDatabases ORDER BY DbName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old thread, but it was very helpful when I had to put together some system documentation for several different servers that were hosting different versions of Sql Server. I ended up creating 4 stored procedures which I am posting here for the benefit of the community. We use Dynamics NAV so the two stored procedures with NAV in the name split the Nav company out of the table name. Enjoy...

2 of 4 - ListServerDatabaseTables

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[ListServerDatabaseTables]
(
    @SearchDatabases varchar(max) = NULL,  
    @SearchSchema sysname = NULL,
    @SearchTables varchar(max) = NULL,
    @ExcludeSystemDatabases bit = 1,
    @Sql varchar(max) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

/**************************************************************************************************************************************
* Lists all of the database tables for a given server.
*   Parameters
*       SearchDatabases - Comma delimited list of database names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                         Defaults to null  
*       SearchSchema - Schema name for which to search
*                      Defaults to null 
*       SearchTables - Comma delimited list of table names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                      Defaults to null 
*       ExcludeSystemDatabases - 1 to exclude system databases, otherwise 0
*                          Defaults to 1
*       Sql - Output - the stored proc generated sql
*
*   Adapted from answer by KM answered May 21 '10 at 13:33
*   From: How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?
*   Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set
*
**************************************************************************************************************************************/

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @l_CompoundLikeStatement varchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @l_TableName sysname
    DECLARE @l_DatabaseName sysname

    DECLARE @l_Index int

    DECLARE @l_UseAndText bit = 0

    DECLARE @AllTables table (ServerName sysname, DbName sysname, SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname)

    SET @Sql = 
        'select @@ServerName as ''ServerName'', ''?'' as ''DbName'', s.name as ''SchemaName'', t.name as ''TableName'' ' + char(13) +
        'from [?].sys.tables t inner join ' + char(13) + 
        '     sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id '

    -- Comma delimited list of database names for which to search
    IF @SearchDatabases IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + 'where (' + char(13)
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchDatabases)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchDatabases, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchDatabases = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchDatabases, @l_DatabaseName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' ''?'' like ''' + @l_DatabaseName + '%'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ')'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Search schema
    IF @SearchSchema IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            's.name LIKE ''' + @SearchSchema + ''' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS'
        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Comma delimited list of table names for which to search
    IF @SearchTables IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and (' ELSE 'where (' END + char(13) 
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchTables))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchTables)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_TableName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchTables))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_TableName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchTables, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchTables = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchTables, @l_TableName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' t.name like ''$' + @l_TableName + ''' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ' )'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    IF @ExcludeSystemDatabases = 1 BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + case when @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            '''?'' not in (''master'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''model'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''msdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''tempdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)' 
    END

/*  PRINT @Sql  */

    INSERT INTO @AllTables 
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @Sql

    SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY DbName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, SchemaName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, TableName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old thread, but it was very helpful when I had to put together some system documentation for several different servers that were hosting different versions of Sql Server. I ended up creating 4 stored procedures which I am posting here for the benefit of the community. We use Dynamics NAV so the two stored procedures with NAV in the name split the Nav company out of the table name. Enjoy...

3 of 4 - ListServerDatabaseNavCompanies - for Dynamics NAV

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[ListServerDatabaseNavCompanies]
(
    @SearchDatabases varchar(max) = NULL,  
    @SearchSchema sysname = NULL,
    @SearchCompanies varchar(max) = NULL,
    @OrderByDatabaseNameFirst bit = 1, 
    @ExcludeSystemDatabases bit = 1, 
    @Sql varchar(max) OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

/**************************************************************************************************************************************
* Lists all of the database companies for a given server.
*   Parameters
*       SearchDatabases - Comma delimited list of database names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                         Defaults to null  
*       SearchSchema - Schema name for which to search
*                      Defaults to null 
*       SearchCompanies - Comma delimited list of company names for which to search - converted into series of Like statements
*                         Defaults to null  
*       OrderByDatabaseNameFirst - 1 to sort by Database name and then Company Name, otherwise 0 to sort by Company name first 
*                                  Defaults to 1
*       ExcludeSystemDatabases - 1 to exclude system databases, otherwise 0
*                          Defaults to 1
*       Sql - Output - the stored proc generated sql
*
*   Adapted from answer by KM answered May 21 '10 at 13:33
*   From: How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?
*   Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set
*
**************************************************************************************************************************************/

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @l_CompoundLikeStatement varchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @l_CompanyName sysname
    DECLARE @l_DatabaseName sysname

    DECLARE @l_Index int

    DECLARE @l_UseAndText bit = 0

    DECLARE @l_Companies table (ServerName sysname, DbName sysname, SchemaName sysname, CompanyName sysname)

    SET @Sql = 
        'select distinct @@ServerName as ''ServerName'', ''?'' as ''DbName'', s.name as ''SchemaName'', ' + char(13) +
                'case when charindex(''$'', t.name) = 0 then '''' else left(t.name, charindex(''$'', t.name) - 1) end as ''CompanyName''' + char(13) +
        'from [?].sys.tables t inner join ' + char(13) + 
        '     sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id '

    -- Comma delimited list of database names for which to search
    IF @SearchDatabases IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + 'where (' + char(13)
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchDatabases)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchDatabases))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchDatabases, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchDatabases = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchDatabases, @l_DatabaseName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' ''?'' like ''' + @l_DatabaseName + '%'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ')'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Search schema
    IF @SearchSchema IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            's.name LIKE ''' + @SearchSchema + ''' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS'
        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    -- Comma delimited list of company names for which to search
    IF @SearchCompanies IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = char(13) + CASE WHEN @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and (' ELSE 'where (' END + char(13) 
        WHILE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchCompanies))) > 0 BEGIN
            SET @l_Index = CHARINDEX(',', @SearchCompanies)
            IF @l_Index = 0 BEGIN
                SET @l_CompanyName = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchCompanies))
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @l_CompanyName = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@SearchCompanies, @l_Index - 1)))
            END

            SET @SearchCompanies = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@SearchCompanies, @l_CompanyName, ''))), ',', '')))
            SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = @l_CompoundLikeStatement + char(13) + ' t.name like ''' + @l_CompanyName + '%'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS or '
        END

        -- Trim trailing Or and add closing right parenthesis )
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LTRIM(RTRIM(@l_CompoundLikeStatement))
        SET @l_CompoundLikeStatement = LEFT(@l_CompoundLikeStatement, LEN(@l_CompoundLikeStatement) - 2) + ' )'

        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13) +
            @l_CompoundLikeStatement

        SET @l_UseAndText = 1
    END

    IF @ExcludeSystemDatabases = 1 BEGIN
        SET @Sql = @Sql + char(13)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + case when @l_UseAndText = 1 THEN '  and ' ELSE 'where ' END +
            '''?'' not in (''master'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''model'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''msdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, ''tempdb'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)' 
    END

    /* PRINT @Sql */

    INSERT INTO @l_Companies 
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @Sql

    SELECT CASE WHEN @OrderByDatabaseNameFirst = 1 THEN 'DbName & CompanyName' ELSE 'CompanyName & DbName' END AS 'Sorted by'
    SELECT ServerName, DbName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS 'DbName', SchemaName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS 'SchemaName', CompanyName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS 'CompanyName'
    FROM @l_Companies 
    ORDER BY SchemaName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
        CASE WHEN @OrderByDatabaseNameFirst = 1 THEN DbName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ELSE CompanyName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS END,
        CASE WHEN @OrderByDatabaseNameFirst = 1 THEN CompanyName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ELSE DbName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

please fill the @likeTablename param for search table.

now this parameter set to %tbltrans% for search all table contain tbltrans in name.

set @likeTablename to '%' to show all table.

```
declare @AllTableNames nvarchar(max);

select  @AllTableNames=STUFF((select ' SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG collate DATABASE_DEFAULT+''.''+TABLE_SCHEMA collate DATABASE_DEFAULT+''.''+TABLE_NAME collate DATABASE_DEFAULT as tablename FROM '+name+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' union '
 FROM master.sys.databases 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'');

set @AllTableNames=left(@AllTableNames,len(@AllTableNames)-6)

declare @likeTablename nvarchar(200)='%tbltrans%';
set @AllTableNames=N'select tablename from('+@AllTableNames+N')at where tablename like '''+N'%'+@likeTablename+N'%'+N''''
exec sp_executesql  @AllTableNames
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a tutorial providing a T-SQL script that will return the following fields for each table from each database located in a SQL Server Instance:

1. ServerName
2. DatabaseName
3. SchemaName
4. TableName
5. ColumnName
6. KeyType

https://tidbytez.com/2015/06/01/map-the-table-structure-of-a-sql-server-database/

```
/*
SCRIPT UPDATED
20180316
*/

USE [master]
GO

/*DROP TEMP TABLES IF THEY EXIST*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DatabaseList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DatabaseList;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableStructure') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TableStructure;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ErrorTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ErrorTable;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MappedServer') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MappedServer;

DECLARE @ServerName AS SYSNAME

SET @ServerName = @@SERVERNAME

CREATE TABLE #DatabaseList (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,ServerName SYSNAME
    ,DbName SYSNAME
    );

CREATE TABLE [#TableStructure] (
    [DbName] SYSNAME
    ,[SchemaName] SYSNAME
    ,[TableName] SYSNAME
    ,[ColumnName] SYSNAME
    ,[KeyType] CHAR(7)
    ) ON [PRIMARY];

/*THE ERROR TABLE WILL STORE THE DYNAMIC SQL THAT DID NOT WORK*/
CREATE TABLE [#ErrorTable] ([SqlCommand] VARCHAR(MAX)) ON [PRIMARY];

/*
A LIST OF DISTINCT DATABASE NAMES IS CREATED
THESE TWO COLUMNS ARE STORED IN THE #DatabaseList TEMP TABLE
THIS TABLE IS USED IN A FOR LOOP TO GET EACH DATABASE NAME
*/
INSERT INTO #DatabaseList (
    ServerName
    ,DbName
    )
SELECT @ServerName
    ,NAME AS DbName
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE NAME <> 'tempdb'
ORDER BY NAME ASC

/*VARIABLES ARE DECLARED FOR USE IN THE FOLLOWING FOR LOOP*/
DECLARE @sqlCommand AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DbName AS SYSNAME
DECLARE @i AS INT
DECLARE @z AS INT

SET @i = 1
SET @z = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM #DatabaseList
        )

/*WHILE 1 IS LESS THAN THE NUMBER OF DATABASE NAMES IN #DatabaseList*/
WHILE @i < @z
BEGIN
    /*GET NEW DATABASE NAME*/
    SET @DbName = (
            SELECT [DbName]
            FROM #DatabaseList
            WHERE Id = @i
            )
    /*CREATE DYNAMIC SQL TO GET EACH TABLE NAME AND COLUMN NAME FROM EACH DATABASE*/
    SET @sqlCommand = 'USE [' + @DbName + '];' + '

INSERT INTO [#TableStructure]
SELECT DISTINCT' + '''' + @DbName + '''' + ' AS DbName
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS SchemaName
    ,T.NAME AS TableName    
    ,C.NAME AS ColumnName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(iskcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME), ''IsPrimaryKey'') = 1 
            THEN ''Primary'' 
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(iskcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME), ''IsForeignKey'') = 1 
            THEN ''Foreign''
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS ''KeyType''
FROM SYS.TABLES AS t WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C ON T.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS iskcu WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) = iskcu.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND T.NAME = iskcu.TABLE_NAME
    AND C.NAME = iskcu.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY SchemaName ASC
    ,TableName ASC
    ,ColumnName ASC;
';

    /*ERROR HANDLING*/
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC (@sqlCommand)
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO #ErrorTable
        SELECT (@sqlCommand)
    END CATCH

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

/*
JOIN THE TEMP TABLES TOGETHER TO CREATE A MAPPED STRUCTURE OF THE SERVER
ADDITIONAL FIELDS ARE ADDED TO MAKE SELECTING TABLES AND FIELDS EASIER
*/
SELECT DISTINCT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
    ,DL.DbName
    ,TS.SchemaName
    ,TS.TableName
    ,TS.ColumnName
    ,TS.[KeyType]
    ,',' + QUOTENAME(TS.ColumnName) AS BracketedColumn
    ,',' + QUOTENAME(TS.TableName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TS.ColumnName) AS BracketedTableAndColumn
    ,'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(DL.DbName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TS.SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TS.TableName) + '--WHERE --GROUP BY --HAVING --ORDER BY' AS [SelectTable]
    ,'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(TS.TableName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TS.ColumnName) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(DL.DbName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TS.SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TS.TableName) + '--WHERE --GROUP BY --HAVING --ORDER BY' AS [SelectColumn]
INTO #MappedServer
FROM [#DatabaseList] AS DL
INNER JOIN [#TableStructure] AS TS ON DL.DbName = TS.DbName
ORDER BY DL.DbName ASC
    ,TS.SchemaName ASC
    ,TS.TableName ASC
    ,TS.ColumnName ASC

/*
HOUSE KEEPING
*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DatabaseList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DatabaseList;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableStructure') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TableStructure;

SELECT *
FROM #ErrorTable;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ErrorTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ErrorTable;

/*
THE DATA RETURNED CAN NOW BE EXPORTED TO EXCEL
USING A FILTERED SEARCH WILL NOW MAKE FINDING FIELDS A VERY EASY PROCESS
*/
SELECT ServerName
    ,DbName
    ,SchemaName
    ,TableName
    ,ColumnName
    ,KeyType
    ,BracketedColumn
    ,BracketedTableAndColumn
    ,SelectColumn
    ,SelectTable
FROM #MappedServer
ORDER BY DbName ASC
    ,SchemaName ASC
    ,TableName ASC
    ,ColumnName ASC;
```

Answer (score -1):

I used KM's answer and added Columns to it since this one of my most common use cases. I also insert it into a table so I can use this data for a different DQ purpose. Since it took me a few minutes I'd like to save someone else time. Here it is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables table (DbName sysname,SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName sysname)
DECLARE
     @SearchDb nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchSchema nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchTable nvarchar(200)
    ,@SearchColumn nvarchar(200)
    ,@SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SearchDb='%'
SET @SearchSchema='%'
SET @SearchTable='%'
SET @SearchColumn='%'
SET @SQL='select ''?'' as DbName, s.name as SchemaName, t.name as TableName, c.name as ColumnName
    from [?].sys.tables t 
    inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id 
    inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id
    WHERE ''?'' LIKE '''+@SearchDb+''' AND s.name LIKE '''+@SearchSchema+''' AND t.name LIKE '''+@SearchTable+''' AND c.name LIKE '''+@SearchColumn+''''

INSERT INTO @AllTables (DbName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT * into ##DBSchTabCol
FROM @AllTables ORDER BY DbName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName
```

Comment: Any inadvertent user could copy paste this & run this script in production environment. Add a disclaimer that this will end up creating a new table.