# How do i get the names of all the tables inside a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

**EDIT2: Found a fix! I used the number of the desired schema instead of the name. Should've thought of that before, really! And i think the error messages could've been a bit better aswell. Thanks for all your time!**

How can i get the names of all tables inside a database through sql inside asp classic?
The server is running windows 2008, iis7.5 and microsoft jet. I've tried all the querys i could find on the internet (and here) but none have worked.

If i add a ; to the query to run a set of querys at the same time it gives me an error because the statement isn't over at the semicolon.
The master.mdf database cannot be accessed because it's of unknown format.
The sysobjects variable apparently doesn't exist.
I am using mssql 2000 format. (.mdf)
The connection is made through classic asp with the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider and ADODB connection/recordset.

[How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)
[Query to get the names of all tables in SQL Server 2008 Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882419/query-to-get-the-names-of-all-tables-in-sql-server-2008-database)

EDIT:
I've found two folders containing databases. One is in `C:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\mssql\binn\templates` and contains master.mdf, mastlog.ldf, model.mdf, modellog.ldf, msdbdata.mdf and msdblog.ldf. The other one is also in the `\binn\template data` directory and contains master.mdf, mastlog.ldf, model.mdf, modellog.ldf, MSDBData.mdf, MSDBLog.ldf, mssqlsystemresource.ldf, mssqlsystemresource.mdf, tempdb.mdf and templog.ldf. Maybe these is of some interest?

How can i tell if i have permission? Does it give a permission denied error?

Please help! No, don't. Read the 2nd edit at the top.

Comment: Do you have permissions to view the system schemas?

Comment: Shooting in the dark here, but does DESCRIBE databaseName work?

Comment: Not for SQL Server... at all

Comment: @gbn: Ah well - like I says, shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the example from:

http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl002_listtables.asp

Comment: I cannot use `DNS=Library` and the provider i usually use doesn't support that and gives me `ADODB.Connection error '800a0cb3'`

Answer (score 2):

```
USE YOUR_DATABASE
GO
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Comment: Not entirely sure and cannot verify it without a copy of SQL Server 2000, but previously I thought that `sys.*` objects were introduced with SQL Server 2005, and in SQL Server 2000 you would use names like `systables`, `sysobjects` etc. instead. But as I said, I'm not sure.

Comment: Runs, but cannot find `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\sys.mdb` :/

Answer (score 1):

I almost always use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

If this isn't working for you, the SQL user your site is running under may not have access to the system objects.  This is actually a good thing, as giving your site access to the underlying database schema can leave you vulnerable to SQL injection.

So if you do go this route, proceed with caution.

Comment: It throws an error: `could not find C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\INFORMATION_SCHEMA.mdb`

Answer (score 0):

The mdf by itself is useless: you need a database engine (a.k.a. a SQL Server instance) to "run" it. As I understand the question, this is your problem.

Then you can use sysobjects in your database: unless you have added your tables to the master database

There is no practical way to use an mdf directly: if nothing else download [MSDE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=413744d1-a0bc-479f-bafa-e4b278eb9147&displaylang=en)

Comment: I can access databases through asp of which i know the table names, if that's what you mean.