# MS SQL 2008 - get all table names and their row counts in a DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, row

I'm trying to identify which tables are affected by a data update though an application (developed by others). There are more than 200 tables in the DB and I'd like to avoid checking each of them for changes.

#### Is there any other way where I can list all table names along with their row count?

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

List out all the tables in my DB buy how do I include number of rows as well?

Comment: What will you do if there are deletes as well? What if it happens on the same table (insert and a delete)? Maybe create a table trigger on your tables and an additional *audit* table that would store information for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
 ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

See this:

- [**SQL SERVER – Find Row Count in Table – Find Largest Table in Database**.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/08/sql-server-find-row-count-in-table-find-largest-table-in-database-part-2/)

Comment: It doesn't show the correct count. If u run this statement "sp_MSForEachTable 'DECLARE @t AS VARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @t = CAST(COUNT(1) as VARCHAR(MAX)) 
+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + ''?'' FROM ? ; PRINT @t'" u will get the different result

Answer (score 4):

to get all tables in a database:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

to get all columns in a database:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
```

to get all views in a db:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_type = 'view'
```

Comment: hello slavoo. what are the mistakes in my queries. and u also add same queries what i added initially

Answer (score 0):

Posted for completeness.

If you are looking for *row count of **all** tables in **all** databases* (which was what I was looking for) then I found this combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950581/823393) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2875768/823393) to work. No idea whether it is optimal or not:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @AllTables table (DbName sysname,SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, RowsCount int )
DECLARE
     @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQL='SELECT ''?'' AS DbName, s.name AS SchemaName, t.name AS TableName, p.rows AS RowsCount FROM [?].sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id=s.schema_id INNER JOIN [?].sys.partitions p ON p.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID'

INSERT INTO @AllTables (DbName, SchemaName, TableName, RowsCount)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT DbName, SchemaName, TableName, SUM(RowsCount), MIN(RowsCount), SUM(1)
FROM @AllTables
WHERE RowsCount > 0
GROUP BY DbName, SchemaName, TableName
ORDER BY DbName, SchemaName, TableName
```

Comment: I ran your code which seemed to work well so I prematurely upvoted it. Upon reviewing the final results, the RowsCount values seemed off. I added a SUM(1), MIN(RowsCount) to your final SELECT command and found that when the SUM(1) > 1, the SUM(RowsCount) was actually MIN(RowsCount)*SUM(1).  (i.e.: if a table has MIN(RowsCount) = 15 & SUM(1) = 5, your query says the SUM(RowsCount) = 75 ... which is not correct). Thoughts?

Comment: @programmer43229: The row count you see in the table sys.partitions is documented as "approximate".

Answer (score 0):

> Try this it's simple and fast

```
SELECT T.name AS [TABLE NAME], I.rows AS [ROWCOUNT] 
FROM   sys.tables AS T 
   INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes AS I ON T.object_id = I.id 
   AND I.indid < 2 ORDER  BY I.rows DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the row counts of every table in a database. You can also filter it by changing the SCHEMA_NAME

```
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName]
      , SUM(sPTN.Rows) AS [RowCount]

FROM 
      sys.objects AS sOBJ
      INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS sPTN
            ON sOBJ.object_id = sPTN.object_id
WHERE
      sOBJ.type = 'U'
      AND SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id) = 'dbo'
      AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
      AND index_id < 2 -- 0:Heap, 1:Clustered
GROUP BY 
      sOBJ.schema_id
      , sOBJ.name
ORDER BY SUM(sPTN.Rows),[TableName]
```