# How to get list of tables which have rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get list of tables which have rows in my database.

```
Select  A.Name
    From    Sys.Tables A
            -- Inner Join with ?
    -- Or What conditions ?
```

Is it possible?

please guide me!
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950538/ms-sql-2008-get-all-table-names-and-their-row-counts-in-a-db

Comment: @AlexandreSantos I have a database Named Account.

Comment: No, what database type? MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle....

Comment: @AlexandreSantos I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950538/ms-sql-2008-get-all-table-names-and-their-row-counts-in-a-db

Comment: This may also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will help.

```
SELECT obj.name TableName, st.row_count
            FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats(nolock) st
            inner join sys.objects(nolock) obj on st.object_id = obj.object_id
    WHERE index_id < 2 and st.row_count > 1 and obj.type = 'u'
```

Edited to show user tables only.

Comment: It is acceptable but showing other objects other that user tables. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could get the list of tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and then cursor through each table and exec some dynamic sql to get the COUNT(*) for each table. So yes, it is possible, but I don't know if there is a more simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below query help you for your problem

> SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName  ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt  FROM
>   sys.tables ta  INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa  ON pa.OBJECT_ID =
>   ta.OBJECT_ID  INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc  ON ta.schema_id =
>   sc.schema_id  WHERE RowCnt > 0  GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name  ORDER BY
>   SUM(pa.rows) DESC

Comment: Do not edit the code which you want to copy&paste for answers. this will help me:  With CTE As ( SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
 ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 )
 Select * From CTE Where RowCnt > 0