# How to get SCHEMA.TABLES from another database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get a list of tables exist in another database. for example if i have connected **DB1** database and i want to get a list of tables from **DB2** then how is it possible?

*I know there are some another approaches like connect **DB2** and execute insert query to insert schema into **#temp** table then connect **DB1** using `USE [DB1]` statement and use that **#temp** table.*

But, I don't want to change my sql connection at runtime. Because, there are some dependencies i have created on my sql connection.

**UPDATED:**

Database can be restored in same server. Now i am using following query to get Table List from the database.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

version of sql server is 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remus Rusanu has already mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set)

Try this Query

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'select cast(''master'' as sysname) as db_name, name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, object_id, schema_id, cast(1 as int) as database_id  from master.sys.tables ';

select @sql = @sql + N' union all select ' + quotename(name,'''')+ ', name collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, object_id, schema_id, ' + cast(database_id as nvarchar(10)) + N' from ' + quotename(name) + N'.sys.tables'
from sys.databases where database_id > 1
and state = 0
and user_access = 0;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `sp_addlinkedserver()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Example:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'test'
```

then

```
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```

[Copy Table Schema and Data From One Database to Another Database in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/664327/Copy-Table-Schema-and-Data-From-One-Database-to-An)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've set the database in your connection string.

If the other database is on the same server, you can reference them with a three-part name

```
select * from otherdb.schema.table
```

If it's not, you can use a four-part name

```
select * from otherserver.otherdb.schema.table
```

But my advice would be to not do that directly but rather create a synonym for each object that you plan to reference externally.

That way you gain some flexibility if you do something like rename the external database.

Comment: Yes, you are correct the database can be on same server. if the 1st and 2nd database name is **DB1** and **DB2* respectively and server name is **SERVER** then how do get list of tables from **DB2**. can you give me an example.