# How to get list of all available databases and tables in them in order to match them with the given in text box?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to validate the database and table name given in text box with the list of available database and table names on server. Is there any way so that I can retrieve the list of available database and table names, so that I can match them with the one given in text box.

Example - In text box I give [anyDatabaseName].[dbo].[anyTableName] with the list of available database and table names in same format.

I have databases like `[database1]` and has tables like `[database1Table1]`, `[database1Table2]`, `[database1Table3]`, so on. Similarly `[database2]` has tables like `[database2Table1]`, `[database2Table2]`, `[database2Table3]`, so on and I want to match database and table name given on whole in text box with the list available on server.

UPDATE:
[this has helped me little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set)

but I don't want system databases and I also want ids of databases, I will be gathering all information  and then inserting that info in single table.

Comment: You can get this information from the information schema tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 2):

Use SMO. I'll be using powershell as my demonstration language, but what I'm doing here should be immediately transferable to C# (or whatever .NET language you're using).

```
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
$srv = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
foreach ($db in $srv.databases) {
   foreach ($tbl in $db.tables) {
      $tbl | select parent, name;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok - this heavily depends on the database you are using. Let's just assume that both `Database1` and `Database2` are MySQL databases.

In MySQL, you can query `information_schema.tables` to generate a list of tables in that database. So for example, through your PHP program, you can fire this query -

```
SELECT '[' + DB_NAME() + '].[' + table_schema + '].[' table_name + ']' table_name from Information_schema.tables
```

This will generate a list of tables available under each database like below:

```
[database1].[schema].[table1]
[database1].[schema].[table2]
....
```

Once you get this list, it's a matter of searching your input in this list.

If you use other databases (e.g. Oracle), the `SELECT` query will be different (you need to query `db_tables`)

Comment: I am using sql server and concat is not available. @hashbrown

Comment: `Concat` is available for SQL Server see this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: Alternatively you can use `+`. The concat part is not that important for your question. I showed you the basic idea about retrieving schema.tables here. If you think the answer is helpful, you may upvote

Comment: I have used this query SELECT  table_schema +'.'+ table_name   from                                Information_schema.tables the results are [dbo].[TableNames] but I want result like [databaseNames].[dbo].[tableNames] @hashbrown

Comment: Updated my answer above. Check the new query I gave there. It will give the result in your desired format

Comment: The function `DB_NAME()` basically returns the database name

Comment: DB_NAME() returns database name yes, but it returns the current db name only while I want all database list available on my server @hashbrown .

Comment: There is no reliable way through which you can obtain the list of all the available database(s) from a server. You can retrieve available schema /user etc. against a known `DSN`. Having said that, Ben Thul's reply above shows you a possible technique to retrieve database names using SQL Server Management Object. You may want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement to get a list of the databases in MySQL is 'SHOW DATABASES'.

In PHP this would be something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW DATABASES");

$db_list = array();

while($db = mysql_fetch_row($db_list)) {
   $db_list[] = $db[0];
}
```

Then you can loop through this databases and retrieve the tables for each database.