# Find schema name for a given database?

Tags: sql-server, database, schema, database-schema

How do I determine the schema name for a given database "MyDB", listing all tables contained in the database (in MS SQL Express)? Is it "MyDB.Security.Schemas/INFORMATION_SCHEMA"?

I am using EF Core with Blazor, code first.

Background: I want to determine whether a certain table is present in the database.

Comment: Do you want the "default" schema (right after you connect to the database) or the "current" schema (if you switched to another one)?

Comment: to check for tables you can use select * From sys.objects so where name = '<your table>' For schemas, one database can have many schemas. You can see a list of those in select * FROM sys.schemas

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the tables with a given and known schema from one database with this query:

```
SELECT  [schemas].[schema_id] AS SchemaId,
        [schemas].[name] AS SchemaName, 
        [tables].[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas AS [schemas]
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS [tables]
    ON [schemas].[schema_id] = [tables].[schema_id]
WHERE [schemas].[name] = 'your-schema-name'
```

If you like to select over all databases on the server you can have a look at this SO answer:
[How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set)